# Meaning of からに?

Tags: grammar

I have a little question.

> オマエは歩くのが遅ェ**からに**決まってんだろ！
>   グズグズしてる暇はねえんだよ！

My question is about the first sentence. I guess it must be translated like: "You're walking slow! And we have no time to lose!" I'm not sure, but **からに** is confusing me. What can that mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the first sentence into these two pieces:

1) オマエは歩くのが遅ェから

2) に決まってんだろ！

The first part is as you mention "(Because) you're walking slow"

The second part's key phrase is an altered form of 「に決まっている」which means something like "of course this is the reason why..."

Putting the two together, this would be "It's because you're *walking* too slow (of course)!" as if to pin the blame on you for the group being late as a foregone conclusion. The next sentence then goes on to say "there's no time to waste!" as if to tell you to hurry up.

に決まっている translation:
http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B